# Synchronously executing promises saved in variables

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I drafted a code example to better understand Promise chaining and found myself quite confused about what's going on here.

Let's say we have two variables which store Promises:

```
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('promise 1');
  }, 1000);
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('promise 2');
  }, 1000);
});
```

Then we chain them like that:

```
promise1
  .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      return promise2;
  })
  .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
  });
```

The two `console.log`'s seem to arrive simultaneously, although I would expect a 1 sec pause between them. Behavior is the same if I create functions which return promises and chain them instead:

```
function firePromise1() {
    return promise1;
} 

function firePromise2() {
    return promise2;
} 

firePromise1()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return firePromise2();
    })
   .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
   });
```

And only if I create a promise "on the go" (either inside the function called in promise chain or in `then()` block itself), I see promises resolved one after another, with 1 sec interval:

```
promise1
    .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('promise 2');
          }, 1000);
        });
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data); 
    });
```

Can someone please explain why it works that way? Is it about how JS initializes variables and somehow connected to the fact that "Promise executes immediately" (https://hackernoon.com/functional-javascript-resolving-promises-sequentially-7aac18c4431e)? I looked deep into different resources and docs but still seem to miss something important or even obvious... Thanks!

Comment: One cannot "execute" a promise. A promise is a result value. The task is already started when you create the promise. Put the call to `setTimeout` (and the promise around it) inside your `firePromise` functions.

Comment: @Bergi, by "executing" they probably meant executer function which is responsible for a value which the promise will represent after it resolves/rejects. And yes, with the call to `setTimeout` inside the function called in `then()` it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first two promise chains involving the declaration of `promise1` and `promise2` as variables, that is :

```
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('promise 1');
  }, 1000);
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('promise 2');
  }, 1000);
});
```

When you declare and assign variables, the right hand side of the assignment operator evaluates instantly, that is, both `setTimeout` functions start immediately. It has nothing to do with a promise 'being executed'. You can test this by having a `console.log("Print me!")` inside both `setTimeout` functions.

If you declared the promises inside the following functions and then created a `then()` chain you would have seen a one second delay between the logging of promise1 and promise2.

```
function prom1(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('promise 1');
      }, 1000);
    });
}
function prom2(){ 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('promise 2');
      }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was probably distracted by the fact that the pattern `let promise = new Promise( /* ... */)` and after that `promise.then()` is frequently used in docs and examples. Yet, nobody seemed to chain them like that and now I understand why.

Comment: and the trick with `console.log("Print me!")` inside timeouts was really clarifying.

Comment: @NataliaIvanova happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Promise is an abstraction of obtaining a placeholder for a future value (result of an asynchronous task) synchronously. The moment you invoke a function which returns you a promise you fire the associated asynchronous task, not at the moment you chain a `.then()` to the promise. So the moment you define your promises you have already fired the asynchronous tasks almost simultanenously. You better dont store your promises but the promise returning functions to be invoked when needed.

Here is a promise returning function which uses a normal error first callback type async function to return a promise.

```
function asyncTask(data){
  return new Promise((v,x) => doAsyncThings(data, (e,r) => e ? x(e) : v(r)));
}
```

Here is an example of sequencing promises by utilizing a recursive promise sequencer.

```js
var sequenceAsync = ([d,...ds]) => d !== void 0 && asyncTask(d).then(v => sequenceAsync(ds)),
    asyncTask     = n => new Promise(v => setTimeout(n => (console.log(n), v()), 1000, n)),
    data          = [1,2,3,4,5];

sequenceAsync(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please explain why it works that way? Is it about how JS
>   initializes variables and somehow connected to the fact that "Promise
>   executes immediately"

Yes, it is exactly because of that. The promise will execute as soon as it is declared so in your case when you declare promise1 it automatically waits for 1 second and promise2 the same. If you want to wait one second after the first action is done you have to declare the promise inside the then block (as you did in the last example). A common practice is to have functions that returns promises:

```
const getSecondPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('promise 2' ));
```

then you can just invoke the function in the then of your first promise and get the second one immediately executed.